# Debugging Nodejs SocketIO server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I upgraded to the latest nodejs on Windows 8 and my socketIO server launches but I can't send messages to it.

Running node

```
v0.10.31
```

When my server is running I correctly see 'handshake authorized' in the command console when I launch my web browser but I also see the 3 following messages which repeat every 10 seconds or so

```
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared close timeout for client foo
```

Is this normal? Or does this indicate something is wrong with my socketIO connection?

Comment: have you tried using node-inspector to debug and verify that messages are not getting to the server?

Comment: thanks. looks like a useful tool. My problem resided elsewhere, but are the above debug messages normal?

Comment: I've seen them all before but it is hard to say if they are related to your issue or not